# RJ45 Patch Panel: Keystone module compatibility

Tags: patch-panel

I need to wire additional sockets on a patch panel. However, the keystone modules from the same manufacturer are out of stock.

**Are keystone modules standardized in terms of patch panel mounting, so that I could use keystone modules from any manufacturer?**

[This is the panel in question](https://www.rdm.com/R-M-Products/Twisted-Pair-Cabling/19-Patch-Panel/1U-16-Ports/19-1U-Patch-Panel-16-Port-s-empty/19-1U-Patch-Panel-16-Port-s-empty), if it matters.

Comment: I have seen cheap monoprice CAT6 keystones that wouldn't fit adjacent in a 5e panel because they were too close together for the width of the keystone.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keystone connectors and mounting panels are standardized and should fit any which way. I'm not sure whether the panel you linked to is a keystone type though...